# Problem with printing keypad input to the LCD in a while loop

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd, keypad

this is my first post here, though I have been following this forum for a while (pun intended). I am trying to write a program for a machine that will drill holes in a metal rail, and cut the rail to the desired length. This is a home project, but I am starting to think that it is a bit much for the arduino. I hope I'm wrong. 
Case 1 is used to enter the length of the rail. Case 2 is used to enter the number of big holes that need to be drilled in a rail, after that it goes to Case 3 where it should, for each hole, ask the user to enter the distance, that means that this part will be in a loop, with a condition that the counter is less or equal to the number of holes. When this is done it should go to Case 4. But the problem appears with Case 3. It seems that the loop (while loop) is creating some troubles. I've tried the program without the while loop ( so basically it only asks once to enter the distance) and it works. I think that maybe the part where I need to print the message "enter the value" and then print the keypad values creates some trouble with the while loop, maybe it slows it down.

I forgot to add, when I upload the program, and I start entering the values with a keypad, as soon as it goes to Case 3, the display prints a bunch of ones (the display fills up with 1s)

Could it be that this is too much for Arduino? Should i try to program it like a regular microcontroller, using arduino IDE but not using arduino commands? What do you think? Please ask if you need some clarification about the code. And thank you in advance.

```
#include<Wire.h>
#include<LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include<Encoder.h>
#include<Keypad.h>


//definisanje tastera za tastaturu
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd1(0x27, 16, 2);
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd2(0x23, 16, 2);
const byte ROWS=4;
const byte COLS=4;
char hexaKeys [ROWS][COLS]={
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {4, 5, 6, 7};
byte colPins[COLS] = {8, 9, 10, 11};
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
Encoder myEnc(2,3);

unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long previousTime2=0;
unsigned long previousTime3=0;
unsigned long previousTime4=0;
unsigned long previousTime5=0;
unsigned long oldTime=0;
int loopTime=5;
String niz1="";
String niz2="";
String niz3="";
String niz4="";
String niz5="";
int duzina;
int br_Vrupa, br_Mrupa;
int state=1;
int debounce=400;
int i=1;
int m=1;
int j,k,n;
int zad_vrV [30], zad_vrM [30];
int start_taster, previous_state; //button that signals the start
int encoder_reading;
int prev_vr;
int zbir;
int error=5; 
bool testRange1=true;
bool testRange2=true;
bool testRange3=true;
int machine_start=14; //relay that moves the rail
int relay1=15;  //relay for big holes
int relay2=16;  //relay for small holes
int relay3=17;  //relay for cutting the rail
int dt=2000;

void setup(){
  lcd1.init();  //printing values from the encoder
  lcd2.init();  //printing values from the keypad
  lcd1.backlight();
  lcd2.backlight();
  pinMode(12,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(machine_start,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT);
}


void loop(){
  char keyin=customKeypad.getKey();
  lcd1.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd2.setCursor(0,0);
  currentTime=millis();
  switch (state) {
    case 1:
    lcd2.print("Uneti duzinu:");
    if(keyin){
      if(isDigit(keyin)){   //proverava da li je uneta vrednost neka cifra
      niz1 += (char)keyin;    //od unetih cifara kreira niz
      lcd2.clear();
      lcd2.setCursor(0,1);
      delay(10);
      lcd2.print(niz1);
      duzina=niz1.toInt();     //konvertuje dobijeni niz u broj (int)
      }
      else if (keyin=='#'){
      niz1.remove(0);
      duzina=niz1.toInt();
      lcd2.clear();
      delay(10);
      lcd2.print(duzina);
      }

      if(keyin=='A'){
        state=2;
        lcd2.clear();
        delay(10);
    }
  }
    break;

    case 2:

    lcd2.print("Uneti br V");  //enter the number of big holes
    if(keyin){
      if(isDigit(keyin)){
        niz2+=(char)keyin;
        lcd2.clear();
        delay(10);
        lcd2.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd2.print(niz2);
        br_Vrupa=niz2.toInt();
        }
      else if (keyin=='#'){
        niz2.remove(0);
        br_Vrupa=niz2.toInt();
        lcd2.clear();
        delay(10);
        lcd2.print(br_Vrupa);
    }

    if(keyin=='A'){
        state=3;
        lcd2.clear();
        delay(10);
      }
    }
    break;

    case 3: //this case is used to enter the length to the each big hole

    while(i<=br_Vrupa);{
      j=i-1;
      if(keyin){
        if(isDigit(keyin)){
         niz3+=(char)keyin;
         lcd2.print("enter length ");
         lcd2.print(i);
         delay(10);
         lcd2.print(niz3);
         zad_vrV[j]=niz3.toInt();
        }
        else if (keyin=='#'){
          niz3.remove(0);
          zad_vrV[j]=niz3.toInt();
          lcd2.clear();
          delay(10);
          lcd2.print(zad_vrV[j]);
        }
      }
       if(keyin=='A'){
         i++;
         }
      if(i==br_Vrupa){  //when counter i reaches the br_Vrupa value, switch to the next case
        state=4;
      }
    }

      break;

      case 4:
      lcd2.clear();
      delay(10);
      lcd2.print("Uneti br M"); //enter the number of small holes
      if(keyin){
        if(isDigit(keyin)){
        niz4+=(char)keyin;
        lcd2.clear();
        lcd2.setCursor(0,1);
        delay(10);
        lcd2.print(niz4);
        br_Mrupa=niz4.toInt();
        }
        else if (keyin=='#'){
        niz4.remove(0);
        br_Mrupa=niz4.toInt();
        lcd2.clear();
        delay(10);
        lcd2.print(br_Mrupa);
        }
       if(keyin=='A'){
        state=5;
        lcd2.clear();
        delay(10);
        }
       }
      break;

      case 5: //this case is used to enter the length to the each small hole
      lcd2.clear();
      delay(10);
      while(m <= br_Mrupa){
        lcd2.print("enter length ");
        lcd2.print(m);
        n=m-1;
        if(keyin){
          if(isDigit(keyin)){
          niz5+=(char)keyin;
          lcd2.clear();
          lcd2.setCursor(0,1);
          delay(10);
          lcd2.print(niz5);
          zad_vrM[n]=niz5.toInt();
        }
        else if (keyin=='#'){
          niz5.remove(0);
          zad_vrM[n]=niz5.toInt();
          lcd2.clear();
          delay(10);
          lcd2.print(zad_vrM[n]);
        }

       if(keyin=='A'){
         m++;
        lcd2.clear();
        ;
         }
        }
      break;
  }

}
  start_taster=digitalRead(12);
  if(start_taster==LOW && previous_state==HIGH && currentTime-previousTime2 > debounce){
    previousTime2=currentTime;
    digitalWrite(machine_start,HIGH);
  }
  previous_state=start_taster;
  encoder_reading=(myEnc.read())*446/400;
  if(encoder_reading!=prev_vr){
    lcd1.clear();
    delay(10);
    prev_vr=encoder_reading;
  }
  lcd1.print(encoder_reading);

  zbir=br_Vrupa+br_Mrupa;
  for(k=0;k<zbir;k++){
    if(encoder_reading>=zad_vrV[k] && encoder_reading<zad_vrM[k]-tolerance && encoder_reading>zad_vrM[k]+tolerance && testRange1){
      digitalWrite(machine_start,LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay1,HIGH);
      previousTime3=currentTime;
      testRange1=false;
      if(currentTime-previousTime3 >= dt){
        previousTime3=currentTime;
        digitalWrite(relay1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(machine_start,HIGH);
      }
      if(encoder_reading<(zad_vrV[k]-error) || encoder_reading>=(zad_vrV[k]+error)){
        testRange1=true;
      }
    }
    else if(encoder_reading>=zad_vrM[k] && encoder_reading<zad_vrV[k]-tolerance && encoder_reading>zad_vrV[k]+tolerance && testRange2){
      digitalWrite(machine_start,LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay2,HIGH);
      previousTime4=currentTime;
      testRange2=false;
      if(currentTime-previousTime4 >= dt){
        previousTime4=currentTime;
        digitalWrite(relay2,LOW);
        digitalWrite(machine_start,HIGH);
      }
      if(encoder_reading<(zad_vrM[k]-error) || encoder_reading>=(zad_vrM[k]+error)){
        testRange2=true;
      }
    }
  }
  if(encoder_reading>=duzina && testRange3){
    digitalWrite(relay3,HIGH);
    previousTime5=currentTime;
    testRange3=false;
    if(currentTime-previousTime5>=dt){
      previousTime5=currentTime;
      digitalWrite(relay3,LOW);
    }
    if(encoder_reading<(duzina-error)){
      testRange3=true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't read the keyboard in the while loop in case 3. no it is not too much for Arduino. (it is nothing compared to what it can)

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant. I thought that this part reads the keypad:

if(keyin){
        if(isDigit(keyin)){
         niz3+=(char)keyin;

Comment: `while(i<=br_Vrupa);{` probably there is a misplaced semicolon (;) If `i<=br_Vrupa` the while loop is never exited an the block below is newer executed.

Comment: You are right, I've corrected that, but it still doesn't work. Now, when it enters Case3 it just keeps displaying "enter the length enter the length enter the length " over and over

Comment: `customKeypad.getKey()` reads the key